# Capybara test that on change script works and adds attribute to the HTML field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

There is a form with multiple fields. There is one field which we need to have instant validation on (email field). The instant validation works but I am struggling to find a way to add automated tests to it.

JS:

```
function addEvent(node, type, callback) {
  if (node.addEventListener) {
    node.addEventListener(type, function(e) {
      callback(e, e.target);
    }, false);
  } else if (node.attachEvent) {
    node.attachEvent('on' + type, function(e) {
      callback(e, e.srcElement);
    });
  }
}

 function shouldBeValidated(field) {
  return (
    !(field.getAttribute("readonly") || field.readonly) &&
    !(field.getAttribute("disabled") || field.disabled) &&
    (field.getAttribute("pattern") || field.getAttribute("required"))
  );
}

 function instantValidation(field) {
  if (shouldBeValidated(field)) {
    const invalid =
      (field.getAttribute("required") && !field.value) ||
      (field.getAttribute("pattern") && field.value && !new RegExp(field.getAttribute("pattern")).test(field.value));

     if (!invalid && field.getAttribute("aria-invalid")) {
      field.removeAttribute("aria-invalid");
    } else if (invalid && !field.getAttribute("aria-invalid")) {
      field.setAttribute("aria-invalid", "true");
    }
  }
}

 const inputToValidate = document.getElementById("contact_email_instant_validation");

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  addEvent(inputToValidate, "change", function(e, target) {
    instantValidation(target);
  });
})
```

HTML:

```
<label class="control-label email optional" for="check_sale_customer_contact_email">Contact email</label>
<input
  aria-required="true"
  id="contact_email_instant_validation"
  class="form-control string tel optional"
  name="check_sale[customer][contact_email]"
  pattern="^(([-\w\d]+)(\.[-\w\d]+)*@([-\w\d]+)(\.[-\w\d]+)*(\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}|[\d]{1,3})){1,2})$"
  required="required"
  spellcheck="false"
  size="100"
  title="Customer contact email"
  type="email">
```

Spec:

```
it "adds aria-invalid attribute" do
  fill_in("contact_email_instant_validation", with: "invalid.email")
  # Trigger the onchange evant
  page.execute_script("$('#contact_email_instant_validation').trigger('change');")
  # Expect html aria-invalid
  expect(page).to have_selector("input[aria-invalid='\"true\"]")
end
```

The spec is red, `page.execute_script` returns `nil` and I don't understand if this thing is at all possible to test.

Test logs:

```
12:33:08.190 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "chromeOptions": {
    "w3c": false
  },
  "cssSelectorsEnabled": true,
  "javascriptEnabled": true,
  "loggingPrefs": {
    "browser": "ALL"
  },
  "nativeEvents": false,
  "rotatable": false,
  "takesScreenshot": false,
  "version": ""
}
12:33:08.190 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b07dc18a74666574f19176731995c-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1155}) on port 26448
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1563539588.250][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
12:33:10.078 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: OSS
12:33:10.263 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session c4e2161e818136d450f5a2cba943cd72 (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
12:33:19.567 INFO [ActiveSessions$1.onStop] - Removing session c4e2161e818136d450f5a2cba943cd72 (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `execute_script` to trigger events on the page. It would allow to do things a user couldn't and can therefore completely invalidate your test. Instead you should just be doing what a user would do on the page.

In this case you're relying on the `change` event which isn't triggered until the input loses focus - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event. There are mutliple ways to cause an element to lose focus (clicking on a different element, etc) but the easiest in this case is probably to just press the tab key. Since `fill_in` returns the element that was filled in, you can just chain onto it

```
fill_in("contact_email_instant_validation", with: "invalid.email").send_keys(:tab)
# Expect html aria-invalid
expect(page).to have_selector("input[aria-invalid='true']") # could probably just be simpler as "input[aria-invalid]"
```

Note: I also fixed the final selector you're expecting

Comment: I have no idea why this won't work, spec fails with `but there were no matches`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko What is the complete failure message? Using the code you have above, this gist https://gist.github.com/twalpole/fc93318e4778e74e396c42c892b3fdfe shows it working properly, so what's the difference between what that is doing and what you're actually doing? Does the gist pass if you run it? What driver are you using? What versions of Capybara, Selenium, browser, etc are you using?

Comment: Thomas, the full message is `Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector("input[aria-invalid]")
       expected to find css "input[aria-invalid]" but there were no matches`
System: OSX, capybara 3.16.1, selenium-webdriver (~> 3.14), Chrome (I think latest), rails 5.2

Comment: Btw, when I tried `find('#contact_email_instant_validation').trigger('change')` it failed with `Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError: Capybara::Driver::Node#trigger` maybe it can give hints on what my setup is missing?..

Comment: From the logs I see the following: `INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "cssSelectorsEnabled": true,
  "javascriptEnabled": true,
  "nativeEvents": false,
  "rotatable": false,
  "takesScreenshot": false,
  "version": ""
}`, `Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600233`...

Comment: @AndreyDeineko  Chromedriver 2.43 is massively out of date. If you’re running the current stable release of Chrome you need chromedriver 75.x.x.x  http://chromedriver.chromium.org/

Comment: This is what I seen from the logs, I checked Gemfile (and Gemfile.lock) - it doesn't seem that we specify the version of it. How can I fix that? Is it specifiable in the Gemfile?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko  easiest way is to use the ‘webdrivers’ gem  (remove the ‘chromedriver-helper’ gem if you have that installed

Comment: Thank you very much for all the time you have already dedicated! I will try this and let you know

Comment: @AndreyDeineko if that doesn’t fix it please try running the gist I linked to in a previous comment and see if that passes

Comment: I will do that.

Comment: Running that test on my local system returns `true`. But our tests are run inside docker and there I couldn't run the file, `from change_test.rb:20:in '<main>' ... /usr/local/bundle/gems/webdrivers-4.1.0/lib/webdrivers/system.rb:150:in 'popen': wrong first argument (ArgumentError)`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko That's because whatever docker instance you ran it on didn't have Chrome installed.  If you're using remote driver instances (which it seems like you are) you can't really use webdrivers (its mostly for local usage) and instead will need to figure out what you're using to provide the browser and chromedriver and get them updated.

Comment: In `capybara.rb` there's these settings: `Capybara.register_driver :selenium_remote_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :remote,
    url: selenium_hub_url,
    desired_capabilities: :chrome
  )
end` and `driven_by :selenium_remote_chrome`

Comment: when I updated both gems to the latest versions the ChromeDriver in logs is still the same, so it probably isn't dependant on the gem version

Comment: @AndreyDeineko yes, as I said you need to figure out where your browser and chromedriver are being provided and update those (Docker images, real machines registered to a selenium hub, etc).

Comment: Yes, I found which image we use (`selenium/standalone-chrome`) and I'll try to update it, thanks for your patience Thomas!

Comment: Hey Thomas, I was able to updated the chrome driver but the error is basically the same - it looks to not find the match (I updated the question with the logs)

Comment: The screenshots which are made automatically show that JS does not work during the test

Comment: But I understand there's not much else you can do, thanks for all your input!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Yeah - sorry - It definitely should work (as shown by the gist)  - I guess the only other question is what probably should have been the first one - Are you 100% sure the functionality actually works in the app when the assets are built for the test/production environment (ie - not in the dev environment where JS assets aren't concatenated)?

Comment: No, I only actually tested it locally in dev env. I'll see whether or works in prod env. This is a good question

Comment: I needed to precompile assets for specs - it wasn't updated automatically. Otherwise all is good. Thanks for the time you dedicated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to execute code manually (it's also a bad idea to put javascript on your test, it's harder to maintain)

Try this:

```
find('#contact_email_instant_validation').trigger('change')
```

Comment: ‘trigger’ only works in some drivers and (like ‘execute_script’) shouldn’t be used in tests unless absolutely necessary since it can do things a user never could thereby making the test pointless